# Parse not valid html via xslt with nginx and proxy

Tags: html, xslt, proxy, nginx

I pass html from intranet to Internet via nginx. I want to make some transforms with html files.
I use such fragment at my nginx.conf

```
    location /news/ {
            proxy_pass      http://news.intranet/$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header Host news.intranet;
            xslt_types text/html;
            xslt_stylesheet /var/www/www/style-news.xsl;
    }
```

But if html is not valid, I got messages like "Opening and ending tag mismatch" at my error.log. May be other.

How can I control and avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. In the general case, HTML can not be parsed by XML parsers. It would work only if you use well-formed XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of Nginx's XSLT module doesn't support HTML as it currently uses an XML parser.  That said, it is possible to patch the XSLT module to include support for HTML transformations.  A patch for the current stable version of Nginx (1.4.2 at time of writing) is available at https://github.com/jcu-eresearch/nginx-custom-build/blob/master/nginx-xslt-html-parser.patch.  You will need to apply this patch and recompile Nginx, ensuring that you configure your compilation with `--with-http_xslt_module` support.  The original patch for an earlier version (circa v1.1) of Nginx was originally from https://bitbucket.org/lrowe/nginx-xslt-html-parser.

Instructions for configuring this patched version of Nginx are located at
http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/deployment.html#nginx.  So, in your case, configuring Nginx would look like this:

```
location /news/ {
    proxy_pass         http://news.intranet/$request_uri;
    proxy_set_header   Host news.intranet;
    xslt_stylesheet    /var/www/www/style-news.xsl;
    xslt_html_parser   on;
    xslt_types         text/html;
}
```

This enables the special HTML parser, and enables the parser for HTML content types.